# How to correct a variable for unit root?

Tags: time-series

So I have done my dickey fuller test on the variable exchange rate. The result table indicated that I do have unit. In addition, I have tried lagging the variable but still ended with a result that say there is unit root. My question, how do i correct for unit?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried lagging the variable?" In many finance settings, you would expect log differences (basically percent change) of some price process to be stationary. That is, compute $y_t = \log x_t - \log x_{t-1}$.

Comment: I took the difference of the variable

Comment: I'd try taking the difference of the logarithm.

Comment: I get to understand that variables such as exchange rate is usually does have a unit root. the question is how to correct for it? Also, how to correct it using stata

Comment: Please don't post questions several times

Comment: Wow! Thanks it works, but how do explain this in my methodology? As in not sure how to explain it in written terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try differencing $x_{t}-x_{t-1}$ and test again. You might also use differences of the logs to stabilize the variance. Sometimes doing seasonal differencing (with or without logs), rather than consecutive observations, will work better. Sometimes you may need to difference more than once.

Essentially, differencing can sometimes help stabilize the mean of a time series by eliminating trend and seasonality.

Comment: Wow! Thanks it works, but how do explain this in my methodology? As in not sure how to explain it in written terms

Comment: Without some additional explanation, this is really more of a comment than an answer. Do you think you could expand on it?

Comment: I meant how do I explain this in the methodology, "differencing xt−xt−1"? I mean what is it called?

Comment: It is called a first-differencing transformation.